# How to add a label on pie chart from flutter?

Tags: charts, flutter

I wanna users see more information in pie chart (example percent of data, shown in the chart below).
[image]

My code is used show pie chart, i tried some function like *displayName*, *labelAccessorFn* in charts.Series but seem label still down show for me

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new charts.PieChart(seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(arcWidth: 60));
  }

  new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
    id: 'Sales',
    domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
    measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
    data: data,
  )
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you're missing this:

```
  new charts.Series<LinearSales, int>(
    id: 'Sales',
    domainFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.year,
    measureFn: (LinearSales sales, _) => sales.sales,
    data: data,
    labelAccessorFn: (LinearSales row, _) => '${row.year}: ${row.sales}', //Add this
)
```

Comment: Yeap. We will use **labelAccessorFn** to show label in pie chart

Comment: I wonder if there is an option which can help me crack this case - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54649930/flutter-google-chart-gauge-place-label-within-center

Answer (score 3):

For other people that come to this Question:

to add labels to the chart, you need to add the `arcRendererDecorators` to the `ArcRendererConfig` like this:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return charts.PieChart(
        seriesList,
        animate: animate,
        defaultRenderer: new charts.ArcRendererConfig(
            arcWidth: 120,
            arcRendererDecorators: [  // <-- add this to the code 
              charts.ArcLabelDecorator() // <-- and this of course
            ]
        ));
  }
}
```

don't forget also the `labelAccessorFn`