# Flutter GoogleChart Pie chart does not render when defaultRender is set to very basic ArcRendererConfig()

Tags: flutter, charts, dart, google-visualization, flutter-plugin

**Chart Displays as expected** with the following PieChart widget.

```
class ABCPieChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ABCPieChartState createState() => _ABCPieChartState();
}

class _TABCPieChartState extends State<ABCPieChart> {
  List<charts.Series<ChartEntity, String>> _entities = List();

  _initData() {
    var values = [
      ChartEntity("Food", 30, Colors.greenAccent),
      ChartEntity("Clothing", 30, Colors.cyan),
      ChartEntity("Fashion", 20, Colors.red),
      ChartEntity("Gadgets", 20, Colors.blue),
    ];

    _entities.add(charts.Series(
        data: values,
        domainFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) => entity.title,
        measureFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) => entity.percentage,
        colorFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) =>
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(entity.color),
        id: "random chart",
        labelAccessorFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) => "${entity.percentage}"));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _entities = List<charts.Series<ChartEntity, String>>();
    _initData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 400.0,
      width: 400,
      child: charts.PieChart(
        _entities,
        animate: true,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Without Default renderer]
**But** when I try to **customize it to a donut shape**, Even after adding a very basic `defaultRenderer`, the **chart is not rendered** in the screen anymore.

```
 class ABCPieChart extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ABCPieChartState createState() => _ABCPieChartState();
}

class _TABCPieChartState extends State<ABCPieChart> {
  List<charts.Series<ChartEntity, String>> _entities = List();

  _initData() {
    var values = [
      ChartEntity("Food", 30, Colors.greenAccent),
      ChartEntity("Clothing", 30, Colors.cyan),
      ChartEntity("Fashion", 20, Colors.red),
      ChartEntity("Gadgets", 20, Colors.blue),
    ];

    _entities.add(charts.Series(
        data: values,
        domainFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) => entity.title,
        measureFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) => entity.percentage,
        colorFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) =>
            charts.ColorUtil.fromDartColor(entity.color),
        id: "random chart",
        labelAccessorFn: (ChartEntity entity, _) => "${entity.percentage}"));
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _entities = List<charts.Series<ChartEntity, String>>();
    _initData();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: 400.0,
      width: 400,
      child: charts.PieChart(
        _entities,
        animate: true,
        animationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
        defaultRenderer: charts.ArcRendererConfig(),

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: After adding a defaultRenderer]

Even when I copy and paste the code from google sample [here](https://google.github.io/charts/flutter/example/pie_charts/auto_label), It does not render. (Neither in hotreload, nor in  Hotrestart, nor Coldrestart)

**This issue is only with`PieChart and ArcRendererConfig.` `BarChart` with `BarRendererConfig`works fine**

I think it might be setup issue or might have missed a very small but crucial stuff, does anyone have any idea what might have been wrong?

I have cross-posted this question in Github [here](https://github.com/google/charts/issues/321), with a hope that this question will be seen by any disjoint set of audience in GitHub and SO(I am one of them). Not for spamming or annoying anybody.

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the type parameter of the PieChart.

Update:- Explanation

So in OP's case, instead of `child: charts.PieChart(` use `child: charts.PieChart<String>(`.

we use `<String>` as type param because the series for chart is `charts.Series<ChartEntity, String>`

if series is `charts.Series<ChartEntity, int>` then we should use `<int>` as type parameter

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was the same, but resolved by putting an `id` in `defaultRenderer`, e.g.:

```
customRendererId: 'novoId'
```

Answer (score 0):

[Here a solution possibly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55221941/flutter-pie-chart-labelaccessorfn-is-not-working?rq=1)

I got with (is a barchart in my case):

```
 defaultRenderer: new charts.BarRendererConfig(
    fillPattern: charts.FillPatternType.solid,
    //customRendererId: "id",
    barRendererDecorator: charts.BarLabelDecorator(
        labelPosition: charts.BarLabelPosition.auto,
        labelAnchor: charts.BarLabelAnchor.middle),
    cornerStrategy: const charts.ConstCornerStrategy(10),
  ),
```

Answer (score -1):

simply remove the `defaultRenderer` and it will work